# javascript: использование браузерной кнопки [Back]

Tags: javascript, события, клавиатура

Встречал (даже в википедии) такой функционал:

1) при нажатии на изображение раскрывается галерея изображений

2) проматывание изобретений через нажатии мышкой на кнопки <- или ->, или на кнопки вперед/назад на клавиатуре

3) при нажатии мышкой кнопки [x] или кнопки на клавиатуре [Esc] галерея закрывается

**4) при нажатии на браузере кнопок [НАЗАД] или [ВПЕРЕД] не происходит перехода на предыдущую страницу, а происходит перемотка в галерее на предыдущую картинку**

Если же выйти из галереи нажатие на эти кнопки ведет себя как и раньше (переход на пердыдущую страницу)

**Подскажите, как это может быть сделано?**

Вроде же как это браузерные, а не страничные кнопки, к ним есть доступ через JS и перехват управления?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: HTML5 History API и вышеупомянутый popstate